# what about the python expression's princple

Tags: python

```
lambda x : '%x' % x
```

the function is decimal to hexadecimal,what the principle? I am python newbie,thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "what the principle"? - How lambda works, or how hex works, or... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In string-format notation, '%x' is a placedholder for hexadecimal output.

The function takes a value and returns it formatted as a hexadecimal string.

It's not "decimal to hexadecimal", but "return (whatever you're given) as a string in hexadecimal notation".

For example,

```
print '%x' % 0b11111111   # -> 'ff'  (from binary)
print '%x' % 0377         # -> 'ff'  (from octal)
print '%x' % 255          # -> 'ff'  (from decimal)
print '%x' % 0xff         # -> 'ff'  (from hex)
```

Comment: There is, in fact, no such thing as a decimal number, or a hexadecimal number. Those are types of *representations* of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 255

#use a hexadecimal format string to display the value of a - prints ff
print "%x" % a 

#create a function that takes a value and returns its hexadecimal representation
tohex = lambda x : '%x' % x

#call the function - prints ff
print tohex(255)
```